# use multiple column selectors jQuery datatable export CSV?

Tags: jquery, csv, datatable

I am trying to export the datatables to CSV and it is working fine. I want to exclude first and last column  while exporting, additionally I also want to export only visible columns. Here is what I am doing :

```
"buttons": [{
    extend: 'csvHtml5',
    exportOptions: {
        columns: [':visible',':not(:last-child,:first-child)']
    }
 }
```

If I remove `:visible` the other one starts to work fine and same is the case with the other. But I want to use both at the same time. I am using datatable export for the first time. Sorry for any inconvenience, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can use: 
columns: [':not(:last-child,:first-child):visible']

Comment: Please use it in answer so I can mark it as correct because it worked for me. @O.Borcuhin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use something like this instead:

```
columns: [':not(:last-child,:first-child):visible']
```